# How to skip the complete left-hand margin

Tags: indentation, margins

How LaTeX calculates margins has already seemed somewhat complicated to me. In my attempt to improve my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43737/lyx-set-width-of-image-to-100-of-page-width) about how to have a graphics span the complete paper with I tried again to understand it – and after reading the answer of TH  to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16419/where-is-the-left-hand-margin) I thought I got it how the left margin is calculated:

> `\hoffset` + 1in + `\oddsidemargin` + `\leftskip`

My expectation was that if I skip the given amount to the left, I will end up at the real paper margin. However, apparently that does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[3]
  \hskip\dimexpr -\hoffset-1in-\oddsidemargin-\leftskip\relax\rule{\paperwidth}{4pt}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

This gives the following result:

[image]

So there is still some space between the left-hand paper margin and the output of the `\rule` command. So which length is still missing?

Comment: `\leftskip` is set to 0pt for default paragraphs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a paragraph break, LaTeX inserts a `\parindent` at the start of the next paragraph. To suppress this `\parindent`, you should insert a `\noindent` at the start of the next paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
 \lipsum[3]
 \noindent\hskip\dimexpr -\hoffset-1in-\oddsidemargin-\leftskip\relax\rule{\paperwidth}{4pt}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to expand on Marc's fine answer. You should also check for even or odd pages, as your code even with `parindent0pt` will fail on even pages rather use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\ifodd\c@page 
  \lipsum[3]
  \hskip\dimexpr -\hoffset-1in-\oddsidemargin-\leftskip\relax\rule{\paperwidth}{4pt}
  \lipsum[3]
\else
\the\leftskip
\newpage
 \lipsum[3]
  \hskip\dimexpr -\hoffset-1in-\evensidemargin-\leftskip\relax\rule{\paperwidth}{4pt}
  \lipsum[3]
\fi
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\thepage` can be something like `Page II` ...

Comment: @Herbert Thanks for reminding me, just changed to `c@page`. Would you recommend one does `\ifodd\c@page\hbox{}`?

Comment: One can more simply use `\value{page}` after `\ifodd`. However this might give wrong results if the construction happens to fall near to a page break: the used value of `page` may be off by one with respect to where the text is eventually printed.

Comment: Detecting odd/even reliably seems to be nontrivial at best. I finally came up with a solution based on the `changepage` package and the `\strictpagecheck` option:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43810/3751

Comment: @Daniel I normally use `changepage` as well. Here I was not worried, as the example was distinctly checking just after a newpage. Test will also fail if the page counter is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

this works for one and two side documents. It needs two LaTeX runs

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{rulecounter}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\longrule[1][4pt]{%
  \refstepcounter{rulecounter}\label{longrule-label@\therulecounter}%
  \par\noindent
  \ifodd\pageref{longrule-label@\therulecounter}
    \hskip\dimexpr-\hoffset-1in-\oddsidemargin-\leftskip\relax
  \else
    \hskip\dimexpr-\hoffset-1in-\evensidemargin-\leftskip\relax
  \fi%
  \rule{\paperwidth}{#1}\par}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\longrule
\lipsum[3]
\newpage
\lipsum[3]
\longrule[6pt]
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```