# Span Figure to Text Width in Lyx

Tags: graphics, lyx

I'm using Lyx and would like to place a figure that spans the text width. No matter what I try, the left margin of the figure is indented, and the right margin sticks out.

There's this post:
[Scale image to page width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39147/scale-image-to-page-width) but I don't understand the raw Latex and how to apply it in Lyx.

And there's this one: [LyX: set width of image to 100% of page width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43737/lyx-set-width-of-image-to-100-of-page-width) which is pretty old, and none of the suggested methods worked, although I might be doing something incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: If you set the width of the image to be 100% of the text width, and it's inside a `figure` float, then it will do what I think you ask. Do you want the image to be wider than the text block?

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me specifically what I need to type and where? I tried adding various TeX code both inside and just outside the figure float, and to the left and to the right of the image itself, and it didn't work. Maybe I should've mentioned that I changed the page margins in Document -> Settings. Also, I'm using Hebrew, hence Document Class is set to Hebrew Article, but my guess is that it's irrelevant...

Comment: Have you provided a `\noindent` instruction immediately ahead of the code that inserts the graphic?

Comment: You didn't answer my question: do you want the image to be wider than the text block? Another question: did you insert the image inside a figure float? (I.e. Insert -> Float -> Figure). As for what and where to type, when you insert an image you can choose to set the width, and one of the units available is *Text width %*. Choose that, and set the value to 100.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. 1) I'm not sure if you mean the text inside the figure 9

Comment: I mean the area between the left and right margin. If you have a page that has just text, then the area on the page that is covered by the text is the text block.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. For both questions: 1) I want the figure to be exactly the size of the text block; 2) Ineed I inserted it inside a figure float. And now I finally understand  how to set the Text Width property properly, thank you! (sorry for the above extra comment, it double clicked...)

Comment: Did you try to uncheck the indentation from the paragraph settings in LyX? Provide a image of your LyX input and the PDF output, so that it is easier for use to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert an image in LyX, you will see a window like this:

[image]

To make the image the width of the text block, check the *Set width* box, and in the list of possible units (where it says *cm* in the image above), choose *Text Width %*. Write 100 in the value field:

[image]